# Very frustrating problem with cmake

Tags: windows, qt, cmake, kde-plasma, kde4

I am having a frustrating problem with cmake on windows. i have the kde libs installed.

when i am trying to compile my project with cmake . this shoots up again and again.

```
 Found Qt-Version 4.7.0 (using C:/Qt/2010.05/qt/bin/qmake.exe)
    CMake Error at c:/Program Files/KDE/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:198 (MESSAGE):
      Did not find automoc4 (Automoc4Config.cmake, part of kdesupport).
      (missing: AUTOMOC4_EXECUTABLE)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      c:/Program Files/KDE/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindAutomoc4.cmake:56 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      c:/Program Files/KDE/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:402 (find_package)
      C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (FIND_PACKAGE)
      CMakeLists.txt:96 (find_package)


    Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Well i was digging around the net for this problem. and i got the automoc4 file which were missing with the default kde-win-installer. So i downloaded the files and ran cmake for the automoc4 and got the automoc4.exe which i place in the %KDE_INSTALL%/bin folder. But luck was not with me. And again my favorite error fires up.

Help me on this!!

Comment: Just because the error is frustrating you doesn't mean that's a good title for the question. Think of other people who might be searching for help on their missing automoc4 error.

Comment: You should mark the anwser, so that this question does not remain open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved** thanks to patrick and the kde-windows team

download the following files from [this url](http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/kde/stable/automoc4/0.9.88/automoc4-0.9.88.tar.bz2)

then open cmake-gui select the browse source to the downloaded folder, and build source to some folder.

generate the cmake , open cmd and navigate to the build folder and type mingw-make.

U then get the automoc4.exe.
1. place it in the %KDE_INSTALL%\bin.
2. Then place Automoc4Config.cmake,Automoc4.files.in and Automoc4Version.cmake in %KDE_INSTALL%\lib\automoc4.

Now just try now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it seems that CMake is unable to find automoc4.

For CMake to find the excecutable, add the %KDE_INSTALL%/bin folder to the PATH environment variable. There might be a better way to fix this though.

Maybe you should take a look at Automoc4Confid.cmake to see where it looks for the thing. You should find that in the *modules* folder under the CMake folder

Comment: Well i did the step what u told long back well, still that error popup up saying "dude i am back". well i will just go through the Automoc4config.cmake for any clues. Thank you