# Linking error while building automoc4

Tags: windows, cmake, kde-plasma, gprof, mingw-w64

I have installed KDE libs. And I am trying to compile kcachegrind. However this error message appears:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Did not find automoc4 (Automoc4Config.cmake, install
  git://anongit.kde.org/automoc).  (missing: AUTOMOC4_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/ProgramData/KDE/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindAutomoc4.cmake:49 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/ProgramData/KDE/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:423 (find_package)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374019/very-frustrating-problem-with-cmake). It seems that he has the same problem. And I download automoc4-0.9.88 from [this link](http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/kde/stable/automoc4/0.9.88/automoc4-0.9.88.tar.bz2), generate the make file with cmake, and try to compile it with MinGW. However, I get this following error messages:

```
): undefined reference to `__imp__Z4endlR11QTextStream'
CMakeFiles\automoc4.dir/objects.a(kde4automoc.obj):kde4automoc.cpp:(.text+0x6b2d
): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5QFile6removeERK7QString'
CMakeFiles\automoc4.dir/objects.a(kde4automoc.obj):kde4automoc.cpp:(.text+0x6b54
): undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK9QIODevice11errorStringEv'
CMakeFiles\automoc4.dir/objects.a(kde4automoc.obj):kde4automoc.cpp:(.text+0x6b79
): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11QTextStreamlsEPKc'
CMakeFiles\automoc4.dir/objects.a(kde4automoc.obj):kde4automoc.cpp:(.text+0x6b90
): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11QTextStreamlsERK7QString'
CMakeFiles\automoc4.dir/objects.a(kde4automoc.obj):kde4automoc.cpp:(.text+0x6ba3
): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11QTextStreamlsEPKc'
```

What are these about? Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some Qt components are missing in the list of the libraries being linked to your program. Try to invoke `make VERBOSE=1` and copy-paste here the exact linker invocation line.